# Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password. (Grails-Spring Security Core)

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm new to Grails and trying to use Spring Security Core plugin to assign roles to users. I called my project "MyProject".

After having generated controllers and views for my models, in `Config.groovy`, I've set a required login in order to access /userMyProject/ :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/userMyProject/**':               ['ROLE_ADMIN']
]
```

Then in `BootStrap.groovy` I create automatically some users and roles :

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def role1 = new Role();
    role1.setAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
    role1.save();

    def user1 = new UserMyProject();
    // ... assigning name, username, password...
    user1.save();

    new UserMyProjectRole(userCwitter:user1, role:role1).save();
}
```

But then when I go to my `UserMyProjectController` page, it correctly opens the login page but always yells **Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.** when I'm able to see it in my DB.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depending on the version of the plugin you are using, it might be how you're assigning the password. Can you update your question with the plugin version and the code you're using to populate the password for your user?

Comment: @Gregg I'm using plugin 2.0, and I only did `user.setPassword('password')`, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Depends, look in your User domain. Is the password being hashed when you use setPassword() ?

Comment: If the password isn't being hashed in the User domain, then Benoit's answer is the right approach.

Comment: I have these methods in User : `def beforeInsert() { encodePassword() }`, `def beforeUpdate() { if(isDirty('password')) { encodePassword() } }` and `protected void encodePassword() { password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) }`

Answer (score 0):

In the part:

```
// ... assigning name, username, password...
```

Are you encoding the password (before version 1.2)?

```
def springSecurityService
...
springSecurityService.encodePassword('password')
```

A good reference on how to [setup Spring security with Grails](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/).

Edit:

Are you sure the user got saved in th DB? Add `save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` and check in the DB if your user is here.

Comment: In newer versions of the plugin, this isn't necessary if using the scaffolded User domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but still get this error.